# Visual Studio Linker Errors for Dropbox

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I have been trying to build projects in visual studio and have grown a little confused. My projects folder exists locally under one of my dropbox directories. My professor mentioned that the issue might be the write permissions of the folders. Some of the folders were read only, though I never changed the permissions. I changed the permissions and am not receiving error LNK1168, but LNK1104 has replaced it.

Can somebody please explain why visual studio is the only program that experiences issues while trying to write to the directories. It says that a program or process may be currently occupying the file. I have uninstalled avast, as that was causing issues, though I have also killed the DropBox process. The error LNK1104 error is persistent.

I could easily use another directory not under the dropbox folder, though I'm interested in finding out why this problem exists only with visual studio and if there's any way to fix it.

Comment: This seems more of a Stackoverflow question but specific code examples would be required.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a "live" DropBox folder, then the DropBox application will be continuously monitoring it for any changes.

As soon as Visual Studio writes any files to the folder, DropBox will begin synchronising by uploading the new data. Depending on the size of the files and the speed of your Internet connection, this synchronisation can take some time.

If, while this is still happening, you rebuild using Visual Studio, the files it wants to overwrite will still be locked by the DropBox synch.

I expect that you haven't killed the DropBox application successfully. I would move your development folders out of DropBox, and just copy back when you've finished a session.